# Installing 'Lightzone' as a linux n00b

Tags: software-installation, apt

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm trying out elementary os as a desktop os and have so far been impressed by how much of my home computing use is covered straightaway. installing a few extra apps from the store was nice and easy, also for an app not in store (spotify).

One thing I am missing from mac/pc though is adobe lightroom. I understand I can run LR6 in wine, but I would prefer a native app over an emulator.

I have found Lightzone (https://lightzoneproject.org) which seems great, but I don't know how to install it.

I've used terminal to do

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

and then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lightzone-team/lightzone

sudo apt-get update
```

But I seem to be missing a last instruction to actually install - can someone fill in the blank?

cheers,
John

Comment: Try `sudo apt install lightzone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ppa:lightzone-team/lightzone](https://launchpad.net/%7Elightzone-team/+archive/ubuntu/lightzone) only appears to contain the package `lightzone`, and AFAIK the new `add-apt-repository` command updates source automatically, so these are the full commands:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lightzone-team/lightzone
sudo apt install lightzone
```

Comment: thank you Lewis, perfect.

Comment: If you can see a checkmark next to this answer, you can use that to mark it as correct. Otherwise, just use the upvote button.